# Lost Grub menu after updates

Tags: grub2

I have 12.04 installed. I made some updates and restarted the computer. Now the GRUB menu only lists 9.04 and Windows 7. Can someone help me recover the original Grub menu that I need?

Thanks.

Comment: are you not seeing the 1st title as Ubuntu in your GRUB screen ?

Answer (score 0):

If you boot into 9.04 and open up a terminal, then run:

`sudo update-grub2`

Hopefully it will update your GRUB and fix your problem.